# Listview in not working properly

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm new to android and i searched code to use listview correctly and I found this video

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iJl1wpptl3A

and used the same code but it's not working.

here is the code

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_disgaea_main);

    //listview

    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    List<ListViewItem> items = new ArrayList<DisgaeaMainActivity.ListViewItem>();
    items.add(new ListViewItem()
    {{
        ThumbnailResource = R.drawable.laharlsprite;
        Title = "Laharl";
        Subtitle = "Overlord";
    }});
    items.add(new ListViewItem()
    {{
        ThumbnailResource = R.drawable.etnasprite;
        Title = "Etna";
        Subtitle = "Vassal";
    }});

    CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this, items);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    //imagenes

    ImageView logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
logo.setImageResource(R.drawable.logodisgaea);
//logo.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.disgaea_main, menu);
    return true;
}       


//Botones
public void onClickchar(View view){
    startActivity(new Intent("com.holloe.disgaeaguide.Character"));
} 

public void onClickclas(View view){
    startActivity(new Intent("com.holloe.disgaeaguide.Classes"));
} 

public void onClickmon(View view){
    startActivity(new Intent("com.holloe.disgaeaguide.monster"));
} 

//lista

class ListViewItem
{
    public int ThumbnailResource;
    public String Title;
    public String Subtitle;
}
```

}

if I delete this code

```
CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this, items);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

then it's working, why??

but not show any content
Can anyone help me?

this is my logcat

```
05-17 07:41:30.804: D/AndroidRuntime(1196): Shutting down VM
05-17 07:41:30.804: W/dalvikvm(1196): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
05-17 07:41:30.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1196): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-17 07:41:30.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1196): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.holloe.disgaeaguide/com.holloe.disgaeaguide.DisgaeaMainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-17 07:41:30.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
05-17 07:41:30.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
05-17 07:41:30.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
05-17 07:41:30.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
05-17 07:41:30.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-17 07:41:30.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-17 07:41:30.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
05-17 07:41:30.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 07:41:30.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-17 07:41:30.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-17 07:41:30.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-17 07:41:30.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-17 07:41:30.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1196): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-17 07:41:30.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at com.holloe.disgaeaguide.DisgaeaMainActivity.onCreate(DisgaeaMainActivity.java:40)
05-17 07:41:30.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-17 07:41:30.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-17 07:41:30.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
05-17 07:41:30.814: E/AndroidRuntime(1196):     ... 11 more
```

this is my adapter code

```
LayoutInflater inflater;
List<com.holloe.disgaeaguide.DisgaeaMainActivity.ListViewItem> items;

public CustomListViewAdapter(Activity context, List<ListViewItem> items) {  
    super();

    this.items = items;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override  
public int getCount() {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    return items.size();  
}  

@Override  
public Object getItem(int position) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    return null;  
}  

@Override  
public long getItemId(int position) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    return 0;  
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

    ListViewItem item = items.get(position);

    View vi=convertView;

    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, null);

    ImageView imgThumbnail =(ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imgThumbnail);
    TextView txtTitle =(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    TextView txtSubTitle =(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtSubTitle);

    imgThumbnail.setImageResource(item.ThumbnailResource);
    txtTitle.setText(item.Title);
    txtSubTitle.setText(item.Subtitle);

    return vi;  
}
```

}

Comment: have you checked the logcat?

Comment: What error do you get? I would guess the first place to look is `ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView);` - is that returning `null`?

Comment: Your error is a null pointer on line 40 of your DisgaeaMainActivity.java file, which perhaps backs up my comment above. Check if `lv` is null or not first.

Comment: if you can put the correct code, because I dont have idea if "lv" is null or not,

Comment: thanks for fast answering

Answer (score 0):

If you are beginner at Android be well versed with Debugging you apps. Use a breakpoint in the beginning of your adapter and Run your app in debug mode. Once the app stops at break point Using F6 do a step by step execution and find out where the app is crashing. Check if that variabe is properly initialised and not null.

The easiest way to find the position is to double click the Logcat which shows the Nullpointer Error. It will take you to the Position where it breaks.
Include the code of your adapter as well so that we can check it further